# Trigger sub with argument with Application.OnKey if key is numerical

Tags: excel, vba

In `Workbook.Open()` I have an `Application.OnKey` for every letter on the keyboard and all the numbers.

The letters open a sub `LetterPress(L as String)`

Example for the letter "a":

`Application.OnKey "a", "LetterPress ""a""'"`

`Sub LetterPress(L as string)`

The sub LetterPress gets triggered.

The numbers should open a sub `NumberPress(N as Integer)`.

However if I press 0 for example I get the error message (translated from Swedish)

> Can't run the macro (path to macro) NumberPress "0". The macro maybe isn't available in this workbook or all macros are inactivated.

This is the code for the key "0":

`Application.OnKey "0", "NumberPress ""0""'"`

`Application.OnKey "{96}", "NumberPress ""0""'"`

In a module called "Keyboard" there's a sub:
`Sub NumberPress(N as integer)`

I also tried:
`Sub NumberPress(N as string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like too many quotes:

```
Application.OnKey "{96}", "'NumberPress 0'"
```

Comment: Thanks you it worked! Wonder why the letters worked with the old method and not the numbers?

Comment: No idea - your original syntax was also incorrect and doesn't work for me.